# Dialog argument in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am sending the reference of the parent window in `showmodaldailoge()` function as

```
window.showmodaldialog("mypage.aspx", window, winsizeattributes)
```

since I don't want to use query string or session variable. Now I can access the variables of parent window at the client side of `mypage.aspx`. How can I access the parent window variables on server side of `mypage.aspx` ie in `Page_Load()`?

Comment: You would have to `POST` those values to the server, say via AJAX, before launching this form. You would likely need to store those values in session state though.

Answer (score 0):

- create a client side html text box as hidden with a runat="server" and an id attribute,
- insert a value into the hidden box from a client side jquery function.
- read the value server side on postback with the .FindControl("yourId") method.

  Note: Use a new hidden field for each variable you wish to recall.

as long as your modal container exists on the same page as your hidden fields, you can read the values from within the modal dialog context.

Answer (score 0):

> since i dont want to use query string or session variable. .how can i
>   access the parent window variables on server side of mypage.aspx ie in
>   Page_Load()?

You can't do that without using query string or session variable. Possible option is to pass required variables to your modal window in second parameter (you have `window` passed there, as I understand, in order to get an access to parent window, but you can avoid that - there is method `window.opener` which should point to parent window on client side), take those values and submit them with form using JS. Once that is done you will be able to do something like `Request.Form["some_key"]` in code behind of mypage.aspx. But that is actually the same as query parameters, but more complicated.

Problem here is that modal window will produce another request to asp.net which knows nothing about parent window because of stateless nature of web. Basically, variables of parent window are removed from memory on server just parent window request is done. Take a look at asp.net page life cycle ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), for instance). Usual way to share data between different requests are forms, query parameters, session and cookies.